# Powershell Registry Search & Edit

Tags: powershell, registry

I need a script that can find a particular default value among multiple registry keys and change it.

Here is what I can do so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\
```

The CLSID key contains lots of key subkeys such as `{021E4F06-9DCC-49AD-88CF-ECC2DA314C8A}`.

I need to find the subkey that contains the default value of "My company name" and then make a change to it.

The problem is that the name of the target key is not fixed and varies across machines.

For instance, on my machine it is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{04271989-C4D2-51FA-6558-1FD935F1416C}
```

One another machine it is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{04271989-C4D2-9527-CD60-A32EA8C49FE9}
```

How can I get this done?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell's registry provider implementation is notoriously hard to work with, but you can use the following approach:

- **Use the registry provider via `Get-ChildItem`** to get all subkeys of a given key.

  - [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) work well for *returning and enumerating* registry keys, optionally via wildcard expressions.
  - Things get problematic when trying to *work with the values* of the keys returned, due to the quirks of the `Get-ItemProperty` and `Get-ItemPropertyValue` cmdlets; the next point shows how to avoid them.
- Then **make *direct* use of the [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey) instances** that are returned (instead of using cmdlets).

  - Use `.GetValue('')` / `.GetValue($valueName)` to return the *unnamed* (default) / the given value's data.
  - Use `.SetValue($valueName, $data)` to update existing values (again use `''` to update the unnamed (default) value).
  - Use `.DeleteValue($valueName)` to delete a existing value.
  - Use `.CreateSubKey($key)` to create a new subkey.
  - Use `.DeleteSubKey($key)` / `.DeleteSubKeyTree($key)` to delete a subkey / delete it recursively.
  - Use `.GetValueNames()` to enumerate all value names, and `.GetSubKeyNames()` to enumerate all subkey names.

<sup>Note: The variables such as `$valueName` and `$data` used above are just *placeholders* for whatever real values you need, irrespective of whether you specify them as *literals* (e.g., `0`, `'yes'`) or via your own variables (e.g., `$foo = 'new'; $_.SetValue('', $foo)`</sup>

Applied to your scenario:

```
Get-ChildItem HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID | # Loop over subkeys of ...\CLSID
  where { $_.GetValue('') -eq 'My company name'} | # Match against default value
   foreach {
     # Modify the key; e.g. with $_.SetValue($valueName, $data)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something to get you started.  It lists all item properties of each GUID in HKCU, where the default value matches a partial string.

```
Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\Software\Classes\clsid" | 
    ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath } | 
    Where-Object {$_.'(default)' -like "Java Plug-in*"}
```

You can change the `'(default)'` to `'your company name'` to make it work in your scenario.